# Adding legend to plotting hazard function of generalized exponential distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
hazard<-function(x,a,b)
{
  h=(a*b*exp(-b*x)*((1-exp(-b*x))^(a-1)))/(1-((1-exp(-b*x))^a))
  return(h)
}
a=seq(1,30,1)
y1=hazard(a,0.2,0.5)
y2=hazard(a,1,0.5)
y3=hazard(a,0.5,1)
y4=hazard(a,2,2)
df=data.frame(a,y1,y2,y3,y4)
ggplot(df,aes(a))+
 geom_line(aes(y=y1),colour="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2),colour="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=y3),colour="green")+
  geom_line(aes(y=y4),colour="black")+
  ylab("hazard function")+ggtitle("Plotting the hazard function")
```

I cannot add legends as i am using individual geom_lines() for each curves.
Suggest me a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not plot individual lines, get the data in long format instead. If you want specific colors you can use  `scale_color_manual` to assign them.

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -a) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(a, value, color = name) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'black')) + 
  ylab("hazard function")+
  ggtitle("Plotting the hazard function")
```

[image]